# Stuck at NullPointer Exception

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am Automating add to card process of "[http://www.oyehappy.com](https://www.oyehappy.com)" website. I am writing a code Using TestNG POM Structure . I got Stuck in task where I am getting NullPointer Exception in Handling Autosuggestion. Below is my POM Class

```
public class productPage_POM {
public WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(id="tagsf2")
private WebElement city_txtbox;
public productPage_POM(WebDriver driver)
{
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public void sel_adr()
{
    city_txtbox.sendKeys("gan");     // on this line i am gettign nullpointer Exception 

    String xp = "//a[starts-with(text(),'gan')]";
    List<WebElement> allList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xp));
    int count = allList.size();
    System.out.println(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) 
    {
        String name = allList.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(name);
        if(name.contains("Gandhinagar"))
        {
            allList.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Below is HTML structure

```
<div class="pro_detail">
<div id="changeImage" class="pro_detail_image">
<div class="pro_detail_title">
<div class="pro_detail_size">
<div class="pro_detail_form">
<input id="cityIdHidden" type="hidden" value="CITY-1219">
<input id="hasShippingOption" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="cityIdHidden1" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="liCount" type="hidden" value="1">
<div id="hiddenField">
<div class="pro_detail_form_inn">
<label>1. Where do you want to deliver this?</label>
<input id="tagsf2" class="inp_pro_detail2 election ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="Enter City" onchange="showAddtocart();" onblur="WatermarkOnblur('Enter City','tagsf2');shippingOption();" onfocus="WatermarkOnfocus('Enter City','tagsf2')" autocomplete="off">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">CITY-1219</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="cityNotAvailable" class="error_message hide" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="textbox">
</div>
<div class="pro_detail_form">
<div id="divDeliveryText" class="pro_detail_form" style="display:none;">
<div id="valentineCatalougueText" class="pro_detail_form" style="display:block;">
<div class="pro_detail_form">
```

Comment: When you debug your script what's null? Null pointer means your using an object that has nothing set (is null)... put a breakpoint on your fwilong line. Does driver have a value? ... Its also worth sharing your full error - it will tell you what has not been initialised :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at the Angular website which changes its id dynamically. That's why it is not able to find the id which you have defined in your code. Try to use the other selector which is not changing dynamically. ( I'm not much into JavaScript).